# Date format to be displayed in MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In my below query the ( Episode date, 101 ) it is displaying date as 04022018 but i want it to be displayed as 04/02/2018  but it is not working on my side ..Please help me by re-writing the the whole query here ...

```
       prdt1 = isnull((select replace(convert(char(10),EpisodeDate,101),'/','')
               from AbsAcct_Episodes(nolock) where VisitID = HimVisit.VisitID 
                and EpisodeUrnID=1),'')
```

Appreciate everyone's help .

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Which are you using. Idealy, however, you should be doing your format in your presentation layer, not the DBMS. Finally, (this looks like SQL Server) : [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: If you want the slash characters, why are you removing them with the replace() function?

Comment: @TabAlleman Please help me completely  by re-writing the query for me.

Comment: @Larnu I would appreciate  if you don't want me to use , how can i do it .. help me and re-write the query for me sir .

Comment: @skumar please answer my question.

Comment: @TabAlleman .. yes sir i do want the slash characters .. how can i do it .. ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `replace()` is not needed, you can use `convert()` with style code `101` :

```
select convert(char(10),EpisodeDate,101)
from AbsAcct_Episodes
where VisitID = HimVisit.VisitID and 
      EpisodeUrnID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), EpisodeDate, 101) AS NewDate
FROM bsAcct_Episodes WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE VisitID = HimVisit.VisitID 
  AND EpisodeUrnID = 1;
```

Comment: Convert to varchar, 101 is the style you need. By the way, storing dates as varchar values is not considered a good practice.

Comment: Second comment: (NOLOCK) is deprecated and should be mentioned as WITH (NOLOCK).

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` means "read dirty data while taking more locks". It's a sure sign something is *wrong* with the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know what it means. The OP already used it. Just stating that when you use it, use proper syntax.

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.